File deletion in Termux bash leads to dangling/stale entry in directory as seen on Android shared storage
I'm experiencing a weird problem:
I have a file on Android shared storage (/storage/emulated/0) which I delete with Termux bash's "rm" command.
First it seems to work as expected.
The file is gone in bash and File Explorer.
But if Android wants to create a new file with the same name as the file deleted by bash, it behaves as if the file is still there.
Even more weird is, that if you use the File Explorer's search function (for that name), the file appears in the list, but is displayed with a folder-icon as directory (0 bytes size). If you tap on it, it tries to open it, but also tells you "Operationn failed", so it is not really a directory.
You can now use the File Explorer to delete the file, which puts in the wastebasket (where it finally can be deleted).
I made several approaches to circumvent the problem:

use other commands instead of rm, such as mv or unlink. Resulted in same behaviour;
use a C-program using the OS's remove call {stdio), same behaviour.
manually delete the file using another file manager/explorer. Resulted in successful file deletion, but there's no way to script this.

Btw., Termux version is 0.118.0, for phone software-info see the screenshot at the end of this post.
Here are some screenshots. For demonstration I used an empty file created as /storage/emulated/0/TestDir/test.txt.
Here it is:
Android explorer showing the file
Now look in File Explorers details:
Explorer showing file
Now delete using bash:
Commands in termux bash
(the second rm proves the deletion as Termux sees it)
Check with File Explorer again:
Empty directory
No files in this view, but if ..
you now expiicitly search for test.txt in
the File Explorer - pooooooof - it apoears and you go for the details ...:
Explorer search for file
... just to find that there is now a directory in the same location: And this prohibts creating a new file named test.txt using Android apps. (If you re-create test.txt using bash - e. g. with "touch /storage/emulated/0/TestDir/test.txt" -  your file will be back in Android as normal.
But let's continue without doing so)
So look at this "directory":
[Explorer showing "directory"]
(https://i.sstatic.net/DA49o.jpg)
but if you try to enter the directory, it fails:
Explorer fails to descent into "directory"
Of course you can remove this "directory" using the File Explorer, which I did to clean up the mess.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix or deviate this problem?
I only want to really delete that file using Termux scripting.
Btw. I tried SL4A's python (using os.remove) to verify that Termux itself is not the problem. My python script to delete the file caused exactly the same effects as the rm command in termux.
However, there must exist some system routines that really eliminate the file, as my Total Commander app deletes the file as it should.
Also any ideas which functions to call to really eliminate a file using C,C++ or another language are welcome, I am not afraid of coding.
And last not least the info about the phone, a Samsung Note9:
Versioninfos

Have you tried with a different file browser?

Well, as I wrote: i zried Total Commander and it deleted.the file perfectly.

Well, as I wrote: I tried Total Commander and it deleted.the file perfectly. But if the file was deleted by bash it doesn't show it, however you still cannot create a file with the name of the deleted file. So there IS something in the filesystem but Total Commender does not show it, like the Android explorer does not show it. With the Android explorer you have to use "search" for the file name to see it.
